# How to drag and drop items between different Recycler views and auto scroll horizontally

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, autoscroll

I want to drag and drop items between different recycler views and make horizontal scroll auto scroll when the item is going left or right.

This is my code but it doesn't work as I expected

```
mScrollDistance = scrollView.getScrollY();
int y = Math.round(v.getX())+Math.round(event.getX());
        int translatedY = y ;
        Log.i("translated",""+translatedY+" "+ mScrollDistance+" "+y);
        int threshold =50 ;

        if (translatedY < 200) {

            scrollView.smoothScrollBy(-15, 0);
        }
        // make a autoscrolling down due y has passed the 500 px border
        if (translatedY + threshold > 500) {

            scrollView.smoothScrollBy(15, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
if (translatedY < threshold) {
                            // make a scroll up by 30 px
                            scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, -30);

                        } else
                            // make a autoscrolling down due y has passed the 500 px border
                            if (translatedY + threshold > 500) {
                                // make a scroll down by 30 px
                                scrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 30);
                            }
```